# problems AppDelegate with new Swift 2.2 / Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, appdelegate, xcode7.3

I recently upgraded Xcode and tried to continue programming. My app can't be built. It says that the problems are in the AppDelegate.
I copy my code:

```
import UIKit


@UIApplicationMain
AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        var rootViewController : UIViewController;

        if (defaults.boolForKey("HasBeenLaunched")) {
            // This gets executed if the app has ALREADY been launched
            rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("maintabcontroller") as UIViewController
        } else {
            // This gets executed if the app has NEVER been launched
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "HasBeenLaunched")
            defaults.synchronize()
            rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("setupstory") as UIViewController
        }

        window?.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible();

        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        return true
    }
}
```

The errors are in the line `AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`. They are:

- expected declaration
- statement cannot begin with a closure expression
- expressions are not allowed at the top level
- braced block of statements is an unused
- expression resolves to an unused function

Before upgrading I didn't get all these errors.

Comment: you are missing a "`class`" before the `AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

Comment: You can create a new empty project and see what is missing in yours.

Answer (score 1):

You've accidentally deleted the `class` keyword:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Comment: I have tried but it still doesn't work. How can I fix that?